# Inheritance in React props

Tags: reactjs, components

I have the following two classes:

```
class Link extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <a href={this.props.href}>{this.props.name}</a>;
    }
}

class ListLink extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <li><Link href={this.props.href} name={this.props.name}/></li>;
    }
}
```

As you can see by declaring ListLink I had to include the props for the Link tag. Is this the smartest way to make components if you want to have reusability? I mean, eventually I'll get a nice list like this:

```
<ul>
<LinkList name="#" href="#">
<LinkList  name="#" href="#">
.
.
.</ul>
```

However, wouldn't it be better to have only the LinkList and to define it?

```
<li><a href=.. >link name</a></li>
```

(*I asked a specific question, but I also aim to better understand the matter of components.)

Answer (score 0):

I think you get the gist of it.  If you wanted you `LinkList` component to create the `ul`s and `li`s for you, you could pass it an array of objects with the name and hrefs and have it iterate through.  Or you can take that array of objects and iterate through it creating a `ListLink` for each one.  Or if you only have a few, just type them out manually.  This is a situation, in my opinion, where you have to look at your current (and future) use cases and decide which will fit best.